# math.random in loop generating same number

Tags: java, random, montecarlo

I am trying to replicate a monte carlo simulation by finding the ratio of square vs circle when a randomly generated point of x and y  is given between -1 and 1. 
I am having problem generating random numbers for x and y, because they return
the same value for every loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class monte
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int loop_n = input.nextInt();

        //true false switch for the while loop
        boolean t_f = true;

        int count = 0;                  //counts how many iterations until inside the circle
        double radius = 0;              //calculates the pythagoras c from x, y coordinates
        double x = 0, y = 0;

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < loop_n; i++)
        {

            while(t_f)                  //while loop to see if the c from x,y coordinates is smaller than 1
            {
                x = -1 + (Math.random() * (2));
                y = -1 + (Math.random() * (2));
                radius = Math.pow((Math.pow(x, 2.0)) + Math.pow(y, 2.0), 0.5);

                if (radius < 1)         //terminates while loop if radius is smaller than 1
                {                       //thus being inside the circle
                    t_f = false;
                }
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("" + radius);
            System.out.println("" + count);
        }
    }
}
```

result from cmd:

[image: result from cmd]

Is there a certain rule with Math.Random inside loops? Or am i writing my code wrong?

Comment: you should probably set `t_f=true;` outside the `while` loop again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the `Math.random()` is working incorrectly. Your loop logic is simply off. As soon as you set `t_f = false;` once you will always print the same radius because you never enter the `while` loop ever again. You should therefore change your code to set `t_f = true;` after printing `radius` and `count`.

Or simply drop the `t_f` completely and use a `break;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You set t_f to false and only iteration with i=0 actually does something. All the others iterations just print you radius and count, which are left unchanged. I presume you wanted to set t_f to true before the while(t_f) loop.

Comment: thanks! i knew i was doing something weird..